# qmake generates unnecessary dependency chains in generated makefile

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, gnu-make, qmake

I have the following command involving `qmake`:

```
cd HmiLogging/ && ( test -e Makefile ||\
c:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/qt5host/win32/x86/bin/qmake.exe\
C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/HmiLogging/HmiLogging.pro\
top_builddir=C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/\
top_srcdir=C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/ -Wall CONFIG+=release\
CONFIG+=qnx_build_release_with_symbols CONFIG+=rtc_build -o Makefile ) &&\
C:/Users/mureadr/Downloads/make-4.2.1/Release/make_msvc.net2003 -f Makefile
```

`qmake`generates the file `Makefile` and then regular `make` is called on that makefile.

The `qmake`-generated makefile has some entries like so:

```
deploy_al2hmi-mappings: deploy_fonts
    @echo Copying application data... && $(MKDIR)\
    "C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/al2hmi-mappings"\
    && $(COPY_DIR) $(wildcard C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/fordhmi/al2hmi-mappings/*)\
    "C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/al2hmi-mappings"

deploy_data: deploy_al2hmi-mappings
    @echo Copying application data... && $(MKDIR)\
    "C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/data"\
    && $(COPY_DIR) $(wildcard C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/fordhmi/data/*)\
    "C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/data"

deploy_qml: deploy_data
    @echo Copying application data... && $(MKDIR)\
    "C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/qml" &&\
    $(COPY_DIR) $(wildcard C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/fordhmi/qml/*)\
    "C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/qml"
```

You can see that each target depends on the one above it **however**, examining the recipes you'll also see that the directories created and used are unique to each target!

**QUESTION**
The generated makefile is chaining those targets, as dependencies, when none actually exists and making it unable to do them in parallel! Why?

I've grep-ed all `*.pro` and `*.pri` files - the files that `qmake` uses to generate makefiles - but `deploy_qml` doesn't appear in any of them so I'm guessing that these are tasks "internal" to `qmake`.

Is there any way to tell `qmake` to NOT dependency-chain them when there is no good reason?

Comment: Looks like a qmake bug.

Comment: @KubaOber I was thinking that but is it possible that this bug is actually a lack of optimization? It could be that in the general case, the recipes for each of those targets *could* depend on the "previous" targets.